# Propagator for radial force field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian, greens-functions, propagator

The propagator $K(x,y;t)$ is well known for the (1D) [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator):

$$H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{m}{2}\omega^2 x^2$$

is there a simple closed form solution for the propagator for a radially symmetric field such as in an atom? Assuming 3 dimensions?

$$H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\alpha}{|x|}$$

Comment: [This paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-96925-0) studies the 3D Coulomb propagator, but I don’t see a simple closed form.

Comment: Indeed, since the Coulomb problem has a known exact solution, it is possible to construct an integral expression for the propagator by inserting explicit complete sets of states into the amplitude $\langle x't'|x,t\rangle$.  However, the continuum portion of the expression is generally going to be intractable.